# Unable to get Qt gestures (QPinchGesture) to work

Tags: qt, gestures, pinchzoom

I am experimenting with gestures... and failing.
My code below is trying to get zoom on pinch — but there is no change

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPinchGesture>
#include <QGestureEvent>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QMessageBox>

class MyView: public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    MyView(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
        resetTransform();
        setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
        grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
    }
protected:
    virtual bool event(QEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
            return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
        return QGraphicsView::event(event);
    }
private:
    bool gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)
    {
        if (QGesture *pinch = event->gesture(Qt::PinchGesture))
            pinchTriggered(static_cast<QPinchGesture *>(pinch));
        return true;
    }
    void pinchTriggered(QPinchGesture* event)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, tr("pinch"), tr("triggered."));
        // ... rest of the code may or may not work but I can't seem to get here
        // so I removed it for now
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene(-20, -20, 150, 150);
    MyView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    QGraphicsRectItem* item = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF(0,0,100,100));
    scene.addItem(item);
    view.ensureVisible(scene.sceneRect());
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I followed examples for Qt - for pinch: [Image Gestures Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-gestures-imagegestures-example.html).  I can't see what essential part I am missing - but I see no result.
It is hard to troubleshoot - no breakpoints or `qDebug` - so I used a `QMessageBox`, a simple text placed at the start of `pinchTriggered()` - and it was never shown.

I tried with 2 different devices - a Surface Pro 3, and a custom Android device.

For both, I was able to implement gestures for `QTapAndHoldGesture`  successfully (using the same logic).

So... it seems that

```
QGesture *pinch = event->gesture(Qt::PinchGesture)
```

is always `NULL`...

I hope somebody can find the bugs in my little sample. Did I overlook something ? Or is there some setting needed in the device ?

Answer (score 2):

These changes worked for me (Windows 7, Qt 4.7.1):

- In your constructor, replace `grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture)` with a similar call on the `viewport()` instead:

  ```
  viewport()->grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
  ```
- Replace your `MyView::event()` override with a `viewportEvent()` override like this:

  ```
  virtual bool viewportEvent(QEvent *event)
  {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
      {
          return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
      }
      else if (event->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin)
      {
        return false;
      }
      else return QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(event);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss following in the constructor.

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try the next time I can get this on a touch screen device, and if it makes a change I will accept.

Comment: This `setAttribute` call will not help. `grabGesture()` already does it for you.